# combinatorics - Distribution of Distinct Balls into Distinct Boxes

Tags: combinatorics

As we all know, the number of ways in which k balls can be distributed into n boxes
where each box can contain at most 1 ball is $^nP_k$.

1. The value is $\; ^nP_k \;$ only when $\;k\le n\;$ right?
2. The value should be 0 when $\; k>n \; $ right?

I could not see this distinction ( $\; k \le n \; $ and $\; k\gt n \; $) in any of the book i refereed. Probably I may be missing some aspect of it. Please advise.

Comment: How do you define nPk?  For me, it is the product $n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$, which is indeed $0$ for $k>n$.

Comment: By nPk do you mean $\binom n k$?

Comment: It's generally advised against that you use $nPk$, because some people interpret it to be $\frac{n!}{k!}$, and others use it to mean $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$. It's not universally agreed upon.

Comment: I meant n(n−1)⋯(n−k+1) only by nPk

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the pidgeonhole principle. Consider the rule of products: when you put one ball into one of the $n$ bins, there are $n-1$ remaining bins to put the remaining $k-1$ balls into:

$$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(n-i)$$

If $k > n$, there will be a factor $(n-n)=0$, making the whole product 0.

Comment: Can u help me in figuring out this . In the book, http://books.google.co.in/books?id=yI4Jx5Obr08C&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=distribution+of+objects+table+combinatorics&source=bl&ots=5R4-t_-iIo&sig=Av41RlhLEu8PAZ2Z8wPyE_32D2k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zUe9UdXRJMG3rge2jYDQDQ&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=distribution%20of%20objects%20table%20combinatorics&f=false , page number 73, the twelve fold way is defined. So is the case with many other books. But, the values n>k and k>n needs to be defined right? or is it implicit? Especially for the same question i have asked